# How to fine tune this navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation

New to HTML, wondering how to make the nav bar look a bit better, and I don't understand how. Looking for anyone to help

```css
.navigation-bar {
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 430px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.navigation-bar li:first-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: #000;
}

.navigation-bar li a:hover {
  background-color: #e60000;
  transition: .7s background-color;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div id="navigation-container" class="cf">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About DRC</a></li>
      <li><a href="Products.html">Our Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want each 'link' to be separated by a thin white line, and I want the area that turns red when you hover over it to be bigger, so that it fills the small section that that 'link' is in. Thanks to anyone that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
.navigation-bar {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation-bar ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear:both;
  display:table;
}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-bar li:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
  z-index:1;
}

.navigation-bar li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
  display:none;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0px;
}

.navigation-bar li a:hover {
  background-color: #e60000;
  transition: .5s background-color;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div id="navigation-container" class="cf">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About DRC</a></li>
      <li><a href="Products.html">Our Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

However i would probably use the new css3 flexbox for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set height, unless you really need it.
To make the links bigger add more padding.
Make the li's inline-block, and the anchors block (or inline-block, should work too).
To make a thin line between each item. Use the border-right, but exclude the last element with `:not` (we don't need a line there).

```css
.navigation-bar {
  /*height: 32px;*/
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 430px;
  /*background-color: #000;*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  /*height: 15px;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  /*line-height: 2em;*/
  /*margin-right: 16px;*/
  display: block;
}

/*.navigation-bar li:first-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: #000;
}*/

.navigation-bar li a:hover {
  background-color: #e60000;
  transition: .7s background-color;
}

.navigation-bar li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div id="navigation-container" class="cf">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a>
      <li><a href="About.html">About DRC</a>
      <li><a href="Products.html">Our Products</a>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much @pol, I made the relevant changes, however the links or the background to them doesn't seem to be in the center. The links are going over an image so I kept the background-color on the <ul>, but it doesn't look centered. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Just done, shall I copy my code over and save a version there?

Comment: Save it and share the link.

Comment: You down to help me again? Just need to iron out a few problems